# elasticsearch returns RequestError 400

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

```
GET 31searchskurecord/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    
    }
    , "sort": [
      {
        "sort_order": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

returns RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No mapping found for [sort_order] in order to sort on')

Answer (score 2):

**This is because you might not be having any field `sort_order` in your index.**

You must be getting this error  -

```
"root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "No mapping found for [sort_order] in order to sort on",
        "index_uuid": "n0rYitJtQZ2ku3ahDqsohQ",
        "index": "67297292"
      }
    ],
```

To know more about sort order you can refer to this official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_sort_order)

If you want to sort on the basis of a particular field, you need to modify your query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "<field-name>": {      // add your field name here
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```